# How to add event to google calendar?

Tags: calendar

I would like to have a function to add an event to my google calendar, and I don't want to sync or download the calendar.  What's the most simple solution to that?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be an extension for the calfw package providing that functionality: https://github.com/myuhe/calfw-gcal.el